# Decrement in for each loop

Tags: excel, foreach, vba

Is it possible to decrement in For each loop in VBA for Excel?

I have code like this:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("B1:F18")

For Each row In rng.Rows
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(row) = 0 Then
        row.EntireRow.Delete
        'Previous row
    End If
Next row

End Sub
```

And I want to step back in commented statement. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not use a regular for loop where you could modifiy the cursor the way you want ?

Comment: You can't. You have to use a `For...Next` loop instead as @X.L.Ant said, and loop backwards.

Answer (score 13):

No.

You have to use a `For...Next` loop and step backwards:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set row = rng.Rows(i)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(row) = 0 Then
        row.EntireRow.Delete
        'Previous row
    End If
Next i
```