# How to create a decrementing for loop, to identify the most recent item in a folder?

Tags: vba, for-loop, outlook

I want to go through this function the opposite way. I found that [you can't decrement through a for...each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766166/decrement-in-for-each-loop). I need to make a for...next loop and decrement through the mail items.

```
Sub ProcessItemTesting(StartFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, Item As Object)
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objItem As Object
Dim OlMail As Object
Dim mySaveName As String
Dim myExt As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim myitem
Set myitem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

For Each OlMail In StartFolder.Items
    If (Now - OlMail.SentOn) > 90 Then
        If OlMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            If TypeName(OlMail) = "MailItem" Then
                For x = 1 To OlMail.Attachments.Count
                    If UCase(OlMail.Attachments.Item(x).Filename) Like "*STRING*" Then
                        mySaveName = OlMail.Attachments.Item(x).Filename
                        myExt = Split(mySaveName, ".")(1)
                        Select Case myExt
                        Case "xls", "xlsm", "xlsx"
                            mySaveName = strFolder & "\" & mySaveName
                            OlMail.Attachments.Item(x).SaveAsFile mySaveName
                        Case Else
                            'do nothing
                        End Select
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

This loop goes through my mailbox FIFO. It takes too long to execute as I am looking for the most recent instance, so I want LIFO.

So, my question is, how do I form this for...next loop?

Specifically, I don't know how to:

1. Get the count for the loops end test parameter - [`StartFolder.Items.count`?]
2. Address the `OlMail` item object in each iteration - [`OlMail(x)`?]

Comment: also - strFolder's definition is deleted but it references the desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, take a look at the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article in MSDN which explains the basics.

Iterating through all items in the folder is not a really good idea. I'd suggest using the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662(v=office.15).aspx)/[FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482(v=office.15).aspx) or [Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597(v=office.15).aspx) methods of the Items class instead. The latter applies a filter to the Items collection, returning a new collection containing all of the items from the original that match the filter. So, you just need to iterate through a small number of items and do whatever you need without checking properties each time. You can read more about these methods in the following articles:

[How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)

[How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also you may find the [AdvancedSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Application class helpful. he key benefits of using the AdvancedSearch method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and Find/FindNext methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the Filtering article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the IsInstantSearchEnabled property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I wasn't aware these methods existed. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar such issue and this is how I had solved it.  Let me know if this helps.  The given below code is a copy paste of what I had done.

```
'Get the totals emails count in the given folder
bTotalEmails = OlMapFld.Items.Count
    For iCounter = bTotalEmails To 1 Step -1
        'this will be used instead of OlMail as per your code.
        OlMapFld.Items.Item(iCounter)               
    Next
```

Comment: This does help, but Eugene is right in that I really don't want to have to iterate over all mail items as they number in the 10s of thousands at least. Good, clean solution though!